# how to change the color of the bar if one condition is met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to code an indicator that colors the current bar if two bars have grown by 1% each in a row.

but i have no idea how to do it. I wrote code that shows a total growth of 1%

```
//@version=5
indicator("2%", overlay=true)

perc = input.float(1.0, step = 0.1)

cond = (close - open)*100/close > perc

bgcolor(cond ? color.red : na)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have your condition written, you can use the [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) on your condition and check if it was `true` one bar ago.

```
cond = (close - open)*100/close > perc
cond_prev = cond and cond[1]  // cond[1] will check your condition on the previous bar

bgcolor(cond ? color.red : na)
```

Comment: I want it to show only 2 bars. in this case, it shows both one bar and two bars

Comment: I understand it should be written through "if"